# Different \section for odd and even pages

Tags: sectioning, conditionals, page-numbering, double-sided

I would like to make the section titles look different on even and odd pages. I have the following MnWE with the trivial approach. The problem is that you don't know that your section header gets moved to the next page. I even tried to check the oddity of the page number after the section is typeset, but with no success (that is the "After:" text).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\X@section\section
\def\section#1{%
  \ifodd\c@page\relax
    \X@section{ODD: #1}%
  \else
    \X@section{EVEN: #1}%
  \fi
  \par After:\ifodd\c@page\relax odd\else even\fi \par % <-- for testing purposes
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section} \lipsum[1]
\section{Test section} \lipsum[1]
\section{Test section} \lipsum[1]
\section{Test section} \lipsum[1]
\section{Test section} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/) package. The command `\titleformat` included in it can take an `page=odd` or `page=even` option to give different formatting depending on even or odd page numbers, just like you want.

---

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}{}{ODD:}{.5em}{}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=even}{}{EVEN:}{.5em}{}
```

in the preamble should give what you want.

Comment: I use `titlesec` anyways (not in MWE, in the real document), but I wasn't aware of this option and I'll try it later.

Answer (score 10):

The [`ifoddpage`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ifoddpage) package does this check for you.

Basically you need to use the `\label` `\pageref` mechanism to get reliable page number (and correct in the next run of latex) but `ifoddpage` hides the messy details.

Comment: As mentioned in the [`ifoddpage` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.pdf), it was inspired by [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage), which also provides `\ifoddpage`.

Answer (score 3):

Even though I used another solution, I made my own way to do that for **float captions**, which works pretty well (and the `ifoddpage` package doesn't solve it). It requires the Table of Contents to be included in the document and to be latexed 3 times. It doesn't solve the optional argument for `\caption`.

```
\def\l@xfloatx#1#2{
    \ifodd#2\relax
        \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
        \string\@setxflxodd{\string\@xflxoddtrue}
        }
    \else
        \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
        \string\@setxflxodd{\string\@xflxoddfalse}
        }
    \fi
}
\newif\if@xflxodd
\def\@writexflxodd{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{xfloatx}{\relax}%
}
\newcounter{xflxoddpre}
\def\@setxflxodd#1{
    \stepcounter{xflxoddpre}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @xflxodd@\roman{xflxoddpre}\endcsname{#1}
}
\newcounter{xflxodd}
\def\@usexflxodd{
    \stepcounter{xflxodd}
    \ifodd\c@page\relax
        \@xflxoddtrue
    \else
        \@xflxoddfalse
    \fi
    \csname @xflxodd@\roman{xflxodd}\endcsname%
}
\let\x@caption\caption
\def\caption#1{\@writexflxodd\@usexflxodd\if@xflxodd odd\else even\fi\ #1}
```